# How to hide/fold parts of messages in notmuch

Tags: outline, hideshow, notmuch

I've been trying various combinations of folding modes for Emacs, trying to get them to work with `notmuch-show-mode`, but to no avail:

Given two messages like this:

```
Summary: Some Guy <someguy@example.com> (May 27) (replied)
Subject: About this
To: Some Other Guy <someotherguy@example.com>
Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 13:45:51 +0200

[ multipart/related ]
[ text/html ]
Dear some guy

This is a reply to your mail.

------------------------------------------------
HEADERS_HERE
This is my original mail.

Summary: Some Guy <someguy@example.com> (May 27) (replied)
Subject: About this
To: Some Other Guy <someotherguy@example.com>
Date: Wed, 27 May 2020 13:45:51 +0200

[ multipart/related ]
[ text/html ]
This is my original mail.
```

I want to collapse the part from "-----------." and until the next "Summary: ".

I spend the most time trying to get hs-minor-mode working with this in my init.el:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'hideshow
   (add-to-list 'hs-special-modes-alist
                '(notmuch-show-mode
                  "---------" ; START
                  "Summary:" ;END
                  "" ; COMMENT-START
                  nil ; FORWARD-SEXP-FUNC
                  nil ; ADJUST-BEG-FUNC
                  )))
```

But calling `M-x hs-minor-mode` gives this error:

```
hs-grok-mode-type: notmuch-show Mode doesn’t support Hideshow Minor Mode
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Can you explain what you have tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: Hi @Dan, thank you so much, good to be here :) Most of the process was me trying different things while yelling at the screen, so it's not very well documented. In broad strokes I've tried the following approaches. **hs-minor-mode**: I've tried adding a setting for `notmuch-show-mode` to `hs-special-modes-alist`, but I wasn't allowed to enable to mode in the buffer. Using the same code for ruby-mode worked. **folding.el**: Tried to configure it for notmuch-show-mode, but it complained about unmatched terms. **vimfold-mode/origami**: Tried to configure them but folding did not work.

Comment: If you can edit your post to include the code you tried, someone familiar with those packages might be able to help you figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Hi @Dan. Sure I added what I tried for hs-minor-mode. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "hs-grok-mode-type: notmuch-show Mode doesn’t support Hideshow Minor Mode" error was solved by setting `comment-start` to a fake value. After that I needed to provide custom `FORWARD-SEXP-FUNC` and `ADJUST-BEG-FUNC` values to `hs-special-modes-alist`. I ended up with the following in my init.el:

```
(defun my-notmuch-show-hs-forward-sexp (a)
  (re-search-forward "Summary:")
  (beginning-of-line)
  (backward-char 1))

(defun my-notmuch-show-hs-adjust-block-beginning (pos)
  (save-excursion (goto-char pos) (previous-line) (previous-line) (end-of-line)
    (point)))

(setq hs-special-modes-alist
   '((notmuch-show-mode "----------\n" "Summary:" "///IDONTNEEDTHIS"
      my-notmuch-show-hs-forward-sexp my-notmuch-show-hs-adjust-block-beginning)))

(add-hook 'notmuch-show-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (setq-local comment-start "///IDONTNEEDTHIS")
    (hs-minor-mode)))

(setq hs-set-up-overlay
  (defun my-display-code-line-counts (ov)
    (when (eq 'code (overlay-get ov 'hs))
      (overlay-put ov 'display
                   (propertize
                    (format "\n... <%d>"
                            (count-lines (overlay-start ov)
                                         (overlay-end ov)))
                    'face 'font-lock-type-face)))))
```